# function in K&R example returning wrong string length?

Tags: c, arrays, string

This is from page 65 in K&R. Description says that this function returns the string length. Here is the code:

```
int trim (char s[])
{
    int n;

    for (n = strlen(s)-1; n >= 0; n--)
        if (s[n] != ' ' && s[n] != '\t' && s[n] != '\n')
            break;
    s[n+1] = '\0';
    return n;
}
```

It looks like it should be returning n+1. Is the null character not considered part of the string?

Example:

```
char s[4];
s[0] = c, s[1] = a, s[2] = t, s[3] = '\0';
```

Wouldn't this mean the string size is 3 and that there are 3 usable elements? That function would return 2, which is incorrect.

Also, what is string length defined as then?

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding on the purpose and return value of that function `trim()`. The function is meant to trim the variable passed by reference and return a negative value when nothing is trimmed, return 0 when the string is empty and return positive value when string is trimmed. If the function `trim()` was meant to return the length of the string, wouldn't it just `return strlen(s)`?

Comment: @alvits It's a fresh view to look at it, but it would return negative value only when string is empty or everything has been trimmed and strlen-1 of the new string trimmed or not. I think it's even more confusing..

Comment: @Daveel - actually I got it wrong. You are right it will return negative when string is empty. It will return 0 when string is not trimmed because it will never find a whitespace. And it will return greater than 0 when string is trimmed because a whitespace is found. Is it still confusing?

Comment: @alvits I think it's still confusing because: function will return 0 if there is just one character or one character + whitespace; function will return more than 0 no matter if string has whitespace or not; Therefore function result is not gonna give any reliable information

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that it is simply a bad code. it is an example of how code should not be written. As a rule any bad code contains a bug and this example demonstrates this rule.:)
It is a bad code because at least you are even unable to say with confidence what the function has to return.:) And if it does not return strlen( s ) then why it has to return strlen( s ) - 1 especially for empty strings.

I would write the function the following way

```
size_t trim( char s[] )
{
   size_t n = strlen( s );

   while ( n != 0 && ( s[n-1] == ' ' || s[n-1] == '\t' || s[n-1] == '\n' ) ) --n;

   s[n] = '\0';

   return n;
}
```

Compare my code with the code you showed. In my code it is very clear that if the loop will not be iterated the function will return `strlen( s )`. That is you even need not to investigate what the loop does. If you remove the loop as for example

```
size_t trim( char s[] )
{
   size_t n = strlen( s );

   s[n] = '\0';

   return n;
}
```

the code will be very clear and easy readable. It is an invariant.

As for the loop then it uses the idiom of bidirectional iterators in C++. So again such a code easy to read. And there no any break statement.:)

Take into account that it is  important that the function would return `sizeof( s )` after removing tralling white spaces. For example it could be used when you would want to concatenate two strings.

Comment: ok so when you return the string length (and with most modern functions in c that involve strings), the string length also does not include the `NULL` character? So for `"CAT"` string length is considered 3 and not 4 (meaning, not including null character)?

Comment: @Spellbinder2050 The function returns the same as standard function strlen. So they can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the given implementation of `trim` does not return the length of the resulting string.

It is not necessarily *incorrect*, however.

My copy of K&R (2nd) edition says:

> The following function, `trim`, removes trailing blanks, tabs, and newlines from the end of the string, using a `break` to exit from a loop when the rightmost non-blank, non-tab, non-newline is found.
>
> ```
> /* trim:  remove trailing blanks, tabs, newlines */
> [... code ...]
> ```
>
> **`strlen`** returns the length of the string....

Nowhere does it say what `trim`'s expected return value is meant to be.  While I agree that its actual return value is unintuitive, it's not necessarily wrong since we aren't told how it's supposed to behave.

Also, you may wish to look at [the errata for K&R's *The C Programming Language*](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html) (this example is not listed).

Comment: Although I agree with you that trim is not meant to return the string length, I disagree that the return value is unintuitive. The return value is meaningful, negative means string was not trimmed, zero means string is trimmed to empty or it was empty to begin with, and finally, positve means the string was trimmed.

Comment: @alvits That's not correct.  A negative value is returned only if the initial string is empty.  Given that it's hard to understand the return value even under scrutiny, I stand by my assertion that it is unintuitive.  Furthermore, if what you say is how it's meant to behave, it could have done so much more clearly and explicitly.

Comment: You are right it isn't as intuitive as I thought. In fact I got it wrong the first time I looked. But the return value is still meaningful. So it will return negative when string is empty, 0 when string is not trimmed because it will never find a whitespace, and finally greater than 0 when string is trimmed, whitespace being found.

Answer (score 2):

You're absolutely correct: the returned "n" in your example == "strlen(s)-1";  *not* "strlen(s)".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int 
trim (char s[])
{
  int initial_strlen = strlen(s);
  int n;

  for (n = initial_strlen-1; n >= 0; n--) {
    if (s[n] != ' ' && s[n] != '\t' && s[n] != '\n')
      break;
  }
  s[n+1] = '\0';
  printf ("s=%s, initial strlen=%d, current strlen=%d, n=%d\n",
    s, initial_strlen, strlen(s), n);
  return n+1;
}

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  char buf[80];

  strcpy(buf, "cat   ");
  printf ("trim #1= %d\n", trim (buf));

  strcpy(buf, "cat\t\t\t   ");
  printf ("trim #2= %d\n", trim (buf));
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
s=cat, initial strlen=6, current strlen=3, n=2
trim #1= 3
s=cat, initial strlen=9, current strlen=3, n=2
trim #2= 3
```

Comment: BTW Do not change the string literal.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - you're absolutely correct.  I just thought putting in an extra "strcpy()" from the literals to a buffer would be confusing.  But you're right: one must *NEVER* attempt to modify a (potentially read-only) string literal.

Comment: @FoggyDay: Even worse, all constant literals (including strings) can potentially share space. Think of one giant jigsaw-puzzle.

Comment: @FoggyDay You don't need to use `strcpy`.  A simple fix would be to use `char s[] = "cat    ";`.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, the terminating zero character is not counted as part of the string *length*. This is how `strlen` works, for one example. E.g. string `"ABCD"` has length `4`, which is a natural thing to expect.

On the other hand, the above `trim` function does indeed return one less than the actual string length. Indeed, it should be returning `n + 1`.

The string length in your example is indeed `3`. That's the correct length. The terminating zero character is *not* counted as part of the length. If you counted the terminating zero, the length would be `4`.

Comment: The OP is correct.  The point is that if "trim()" purports to return "string length", then it needs to return "n+1", not "n".  The example as presented does *NOT* return string length.

Comment: I did not downvote, however I strongly disagree with "In fact, it is not guaranteed to work with empty strings even in its original form, since it attempts to access s[1].". If empty string is provided as parameter, then `n` is set to `-1` in `for` loop (as `strlen(s)` is zero in that case), then `n >= 0` is evaluated to `0` (so loop body is not entered) and assignment `s[n+1] = '\0';` set the value of `s[-1+1]`, which is `s[0]`, thus no array overflow is attempted.

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski: Yes, you are right. I somehow assumed that an empty string will make `n` zero after the loop. I removed that passage from the answer.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski in ISO C, `strlen` returns `size_t`, so if `strlen(s) == 0` then `(size_t)-1` is assigned to an `int`, causing implementation-defined behaviour (maybe raising a signal). This should be considered a bug. However, when K&R1 was written, I'm not sure that `size_t` existed; `strlen` might have been declared to return `int` and so the code would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a bug in the book and the function should have been:

```
int trim(char s[])
{
    int n;
    for (n = strlen(s); n > 0; n--) {
        if (s[n-1] != ' ' && s[n-1] != '\t' && s[n-1] != '\n') {
            break;
        }
    }
    s[n] = '\0';
    return n;
}
```